# jQuery Loop Dynamic variable generation

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a list of arrays received from PHP response.[1], response.[2], response.[3], ... etc. I want in jQuery Loop create these variables and alert them. but I get this error in Console "bill is not defined"

```js
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
  var bill[i] = response[i].sum;
  alert(bill[i]);
}
```

Comment: Then do it, what is the problem ?

Comment: Define it outside of the loop `var bill = [];`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I tried that too 'var bill1  = response[1].sum;'

Comment: Ok, Then what is the problem?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I get these bill is not defined. it seems i value is not attached to variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `window[]` that will define the variable globally or you could use `eval()` like :

```js
var response = [{
  sum: 0
}, {
  sum: 11
}, {
  sum: 22
}, {
  sum: 33
}];

for (var i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
  window['bill_' + i] = response[i].sum;
  //console.log(window['bill_' + i]);
}

for (var i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
  console.log(window['bill_' + i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a  specific reason to not implement it with the fix in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995352/jquery-loop-dynamic-variable-generation#comment92895734_52995352)?

Comment: After reading the question another time I have noticed that the author says _create these variables and alert them_

Comment: Oh, I missed that part :)

Comment: can I make console.log(bill1); dynamic too ? Thx